# Cannot get vim to recognize unicode

Tags: arch-linux, vim, unicode

I am having the most trouble ever getting vim to recognize unicode.

At the top of my vimrc I have

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

and LANG shows

```
echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

but when I open any file (for example my vimrc that is completely fine everywhere else) I see

```
:listchars=tab:Â»Â·,trail:Â·
```

And no matter what I do I can't fix it. I am running inconsolata using uvrxt-unicode-color256 in Arch Linux.

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

Running vim --version shows "+multi_byte" so vim is compiled for unicode.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I did not need to do anything in there to get this working on any other variant of Linux I have used in the last 5 years. I do not know what is going wrong now, and simply linking that does not get me any closer to a solution.

Comment: I rerember my friend recompiled vim for do it, As you know, vim has more than 1000 patch , At first test your unicode supported in your compiled or not....!

Comment: Check your locale: https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/system/locale-check

Comment: Not sure if Arch has multiple versions of vim available, if so make sure you don't have some version designed for minimal executable size.

Comment: @derobert my vim --version shows +multi_byte

Comment: What is the output of `locale`? `LANG` may not be the applicable setting.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the first thing I did was run urxvt from the terminal. After firing up two or three of them, I got unicode to show up. My locale is clearly en_US UTF-8 so it should work anyway.

I checked a bunch of posts from arch and found

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=50963

which lead me to try to chsh my shell into zsh. It worked, unicode support works fine now. I was going save doing this until last, but apparently it was entirely necessary to get xmonad + urxvt to play nicely.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything. If changing your shell made vim work, it must be because the shell you were using before loaded an initialization file which included a bad setting.